# iOS Simulator build - undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, iphone, compilation, ios-simulator, i386

**SOLUTION**

ok so while the suggested answer helped to find a solution, this required some work. So I will describe my recipy if that helps.

My compilation problem was probably due to a mismatch between frameworks versions. While some frameworks were injected manually, some others were added using pods. This might have caused the problem and my project wasn't compiling for all simulators.

To overcome this, I deleted all residual frameworks and added them back using pods. However, this was not plug and play. Im using xcode 6.3.x (working with Swift 1) and there were semantic issues while using updated pods.

**here is my working recipy:**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Parse', '1.9.1'
pod 'ParseUI'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4', '~> 1.9'
pod 'ParseTwitterUtils', '~> 1.9'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

full project is now compiling for all simulators.

**QUESTION**

I was working on an app which was building for all simulators until I added pods in order to integrate `Google Maps SDK`. Using this framwork, in addition to `Parse SDK`, required to add `Facebook SDK and some libs`. this was the starting point of my problem as there was a conflict with the `-ObjC` flag

[image]

Since then, **my project is building fine for most simulator**, except for iphone 4S, iphone 5 and some ipads. The returned error is the following:

[image]

Library compilation and build architectures are really new so I was wondering if this was only a simulator issue or if my problem would persist when building `.api` ? I would need to ensure everything would work as expected on devices going from iphone 4S to 6+

my valid architecture are the following: `arm64 armv7 armv7s`
Could someone guide me toward the understanding of what's happening?

I would be really happy to provide any additional information you may require to help me. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Parse framework that you include in the project is built for 64 bit MacOSX.

I suggest you add Parse pods to your Podfile

```
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
pod 'ParseCrashReporting'
```

Comment: Ok, Will try This, but how is it that it worked before? In the same project?

Comment: It worked before on a 64bit machine, right? And you're currently building it on a x386 (32-bit) machine. The included framework is correct for the first machine.

Comment: No, same machine, same code, same project. the only diff is the addition of pods (google maps) and FDSBK frameworks. Apple require 64bit builds now. I didn't had a second to test it but I'll work this out tonight.

Comment: ok so you were right (partially), the problem faded when injecting parse directly from pods. However, had to play with the version a lot...